# A way of listing any links to a particular folder on a site

Tags: html, hyperlink

I was wondering if there was a piece of software, website, or process that would enable me to search through a website (in a similar way to a link checker), but rather than flagging broken links, it would list any links to a specified folder. (ie look through all the pages on www.example.com and list out any pages that have a link that starts with www.example.com/blah/ on them)